# OSGi: Recalculate the Import-Package of a JAR programmatically

Tags: osgi, bnd, bndtools

I want to recalculate the "Import-Package" of an OSGi Jar programmatically. I try to use the bnd Analyser.

```
    try(Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer()) {
        analyzer.setJar(new File(filename));
        return analyzer.getImportPackage();
    }
```

This returns the (wrong) existent imports of the MANIFEST.MF. How can I recalculate the "Import-Package" of an OSGi Jar programmatically?

**Update**
Adding as BJ Hargrave calMainfest() suggested does not work:

```
try(Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer()) {
    analyzer.setJar(new File(filename));
    analyzer.calcManifest(); 
    return analyzer.getImportPackage();
}
```

It seems to use the existing MANIFEST.MF contained in the Jar.
Best regards
Kisho

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `calcManifest()` to compute a new manifest. Otherwise it just uses the existing manifest.

Comment: After calling calcManifest the importPackage are still empty.

Comment: @bl-hargrave When using calcManifest() it still seems to use the existing MANIFEST.MF which does not have import-package (it uses Required-Bundles)